# Referencing a column in an SQLite case statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite table called `table`. It has 4 columns: `col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4`.

If I was to use MySQL as a way of explaining what I want to do, it is something like this:

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN col_4 IS NOT NULL THEN col_4,
WHEN col_3 IS NOT NULL THEN (CONCAT COL_3 and COL_2)
ELSE (CONCAT STRING + col_2)
END AS clue
    FROM TABLE
```

Essentially, what I want to do is say, pick the value of `col_4` if there is a value there. If there is nothing, then check if there is a value in `col_3`. If there is, then concatenate the values of `col_3` and `col_2`. If this is also null, then concatenate a string with the value of `col_2` (which will never be null, as per how I've designed it.

To try and get this, I wrote the following SQLite query:

```
select CASE col_4
WHEN NOT NULL col_4 
ELSE CASE col_3 
WHEN NOT NULL col_3 || ' - ' || col_2  
ELSE'String: ' || col_2 END AS clue 
FROM table
```

But when running it in an SQLite view online, it fails at the very first case statement.

It doesn't let me do `CASE col_4 WHEN NOT NULL col_4`, i.e return a value from a column within in my statement. It's making me write a specific string, which is not what I want.

Is there a way around this that I am missing?

Comment: I'd try `COALESCE(col4, coalesce(col3, 'string') || col2)`

Comment: BTW, `case` _expressions_, not statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you use for `CASE` is wrong.
Change it to this:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN COL_4 IS NOT NULL THEN col_4,
    WHEN COL_3 IS NOT NULL THEN COL_3 || '-' || COL_2
    ELSE 'String: ' || COL_2
  END AS clue
FROM TABLE
```

Keep in mind that the the result of the concatenation of 2 values is `NULL` if any of the 2 values is `NULL`.
So if `COL_2` is `NULL` the result of the last 2 branches of the `CASE` expression will also be `NULL`.

If `COL_2` can't be `NULL` then the code can be simplified to this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(COL_4, COL_3 || '-' || COL_2, 'String: ' || COL_2)
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that. The issue I am now having is this if I run "select col_4, col_2 from table", it gives me nothing for col_4, and the output for col_2. Which is correct. However, as soon as I add the COALESCE() around it, it just outputs a blank, and doesn't give me the alternative. There is definitely something in the second option in the coalesce, as I can pull it out on it's own. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: if what you mean is that select coalesce(col_4, col_2) from table returns nothing while col_2 is never null this means that either col_4 or col_2 is blank (not null),  Check `select length(col_4), length(col_2) from table`

Comment: That's exactly what I mean and I checked and it is blank! To create the database, all the values are uploaded from a .csv. I assumed that any empty values would be null but they're blank. Is there an alternative then for ignoring blanks? Like an "IFBLANK()" or will I have to go back to my INSERT statement?

Comment: The best that you can do is update the table: `update table set col_4 = null where trim(col_4) = ''`

Answer (score 1):

For this specific situation nesting a few `IFNULL()` functions would probably be easier and run a little faster although I'm sure a case expression would work it would likely be long and complex.

```
SELECT IFNULL(COL_4, IFNULL(COL_3||COL_2, 'String: ' || COL_2))
FROM TABLE
```

The function checks the first parameter/column for a value and if there isn't one it returns what's in the second slot. In this case it runs the nested function if the first column is empty. Additional information can be found [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-ifnull/)